# How copy value in other field in apache nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a JSON :

```json
{
  "_id": "gkpYcLowAADQiQiiX",
  "team": [
    {
      "userId": "L2Q6Nd9Z7KhdXgeis",
      "role": "user",
      "teamId": ""
    },
    {
      "userId": "FFsDDYrTLJiCgW5iz",
      "role": "user",
      "teamId": ""
    },
    {
      "userId": "FzqcQEBjbT7TpxQbN",
      "role": "leader",
      "teamId": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

how to copy `_id` in `teamId` with specification of `JoltTransformJson`?

I used `${_id}`, but doesn't work
Help me please!!!

This is my current attempt :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "team": {
        "*": {
          "teamId": "${_id}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and i get:

```json
{
  "_id": "gkpYcLowAADQiQiiX",
  "team": [
    {
      "userId": "L2Q6Nd9Z7KhdXgeis",
      "role": "user",
      "teamId": ""
    },
    {
      "userId": "FFsDDYrTLJiCgW5iz",
      "role": "user",
      "teamId": ""
    },
    {
      "userId": "FzqcQEBjbT7TpxQbN",
      "role": "leader",
      "teamId": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Nikolay, I wonder do you want to get rid of the top level `_id` as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Need to traverse two levels up the tree in order to copy the value as in the following case :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&", // stands for "_id", eg. an else case
      "team": {
        "*": {
          "userId|role": "&2.[#2].&",// to list the attributes other than "teamId"
          "@2,_id": "&2.[#2].teamId" // &2 value of the key at the 2 upper level,eg."team"
                                     // [#2] refers array-wise setup based on the indexes 
                                     // of the team array. The reason for 2 is traversing 
                                     // two stages : and { and starting to count from 1 
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Your solution return this error: Perform Validation
Component is invalid: 'Jolt Specification' is invalid because Specification not valid for the selected transformation: com.bazaarvoice.jolt.exception.JsonUnmarshalException: Unable to unmarshal JSON to an Object.

Comment: @NikolaySmelov your `Jolt Transformation DSL` property value is `Chain`, isn't it ? And, You paste the specification I provide to the `Jolt Specification` part under `Properties` node, don't you?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: Btw, If you check the output within the section provided by toggling the `Advanced` button, then you should remove the comments( the parts of the lines starting with `//`  ) @NikolaySmelov

Comment: @NikolaySmelov What value do you have within the the content of the connector which is just before the JoltTransformJSON processor ? You might see it by right-clicking the connector, toggling `List queue` and then clicking the eye symbol on the right hand side

Comment: Are you sure the struct is not empty and the input JSON returns with valid syntax for every invocation @NikolaySmelov